# Using redis 'standalone' in java application

Tags: java, redis

I am following a Redis tutorial online that shows how to connect to Redis from a Java application.

I understand that there are many JAVA clients available, and the tutorial I was following was using Jedis. My question is, can a JAVA client (like Jedis) be used without actually installing the redis server itself? The tutorial shows a simple call to:

```
Jedis jedis = new Jedis("localhost");
```

and then beginning set/get operations, but I don't believe they installed Redis. I am new to Redis, but I am picturing installing the redis server to be the equivalent of installing something like Oracle, and then using a JAVA API to actually talk to that Oracle instance.

How is the Jedis API used without an actual Redis instance present? If the Jedis client was initialized without the host parameter, would it then expect to find an actual Redis server/instance running on port `6379`?

Comment: You can get an embedded Redis for java package here https://github.com/kstyrc/embedded-redis